# What is the best way to create a Utility dll that can be configured by consuming application?

Tags: c#, app-config, application-settings

I have created a dll that has some functionality in it that is to be shared from project to project. However, i may need to adjust the settings of the dll from a project referencing it. What is the best way to expose configuration settings for the dll to be used by another project in an entirely different solution?

Ways i have tried:

appSettings import

ApplicationSettings import

Current Setup, Consuming solution setting values are ignored/not set, why?

**dll setting**

```
public class ApplicationSettingsRetriever : IApplicationSettingsRetriever
{
    public string LogEnvironmentSetting => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LogEnvironment");
}
```

**Consumer Solution app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
   <add key="LogEnvironment" value="local"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you want the most flexibility you should accept an injected interface with properties that are your "configuration". Then the client can implement however they want - database, config file, whatever.

Comment: Added setup for client and dll use case

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import anything. In .NET, a DLL obtains its configuration settings from the parent application, not from its own config. So for example if you need the DLL to read a connection string from the parent application's configuration, you can simply use

```
return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
```

This will read from the custom configuration section in the `app.config` for the containing Windows application, or from `web.config` if it's a web application.

Comment: And if you want to organize it, you should create a Custom Configuration Section, so all configs for your library/utility dll will be in a section of the config and not mixed up with the other configs. more at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have added code to provide visibility to my setup. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to make something like a `MyLibraryConfiguration` class.

When you create an instance of the object inside you library (or maybe in a static function that will set static values) you can pass this `Configuration` to set the changeable values.